# Which addon to control traffic on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, add-on, traffic, apprequests

i am deploying a python app with a web interface on heroku. I know that I can check the "metrics"-tab when looking at the app but that does not give me much. Is there any other addon where I can check(and save) the metrics?

What i want to see is:
 * Traffic over time(hours:minutes)
 * What kind of browsers the requests come from
 * What kind of device used(tablet/phone etc)
I also need it to be saved so i can check traffic for a month back. In the metrics tab i can only see 1-2 weeks back.

I have been looking at keen.io-app for this but I doesnt know exactly how to use it. What i look for is more like www.similarweb.com.

Do you have any tips on which addon or solution i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two addons you can use here:

- [NewRelic](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/newrelic) will give you performance information regarding your slow transactions and external calls.
- [Librato](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/librato) will graph your memory usage and traffic, and allow you to send any data and graph it too.

Comment: Both of them satisfied the need for additional metrics although none of these addons seem to have the number of requests on the app. Right now I only use free-versions, could it be that I need to upgrade?

Comment: Librato will, by default, log the things you cannot log yourself (like memory usage). You can send a librato entry for every request being sent to your app, and have that data fairly easily.